# Do not cache `lazy val`. Possible?

Tags: scala, caching, playframework-2.0

On a  class `ObjectToBeCached`, we have a `lazy val` in order to avoid multiple requests to the database. The very same `case class` is cached what also caches (play framework, memcache) the object on the `lazy val`. Issue is that the object is rather big and consumes quite some memory.

Is there any way to get around the caching of the lazy val itself or an alternative solution that gives us the nice advantage of `lazy val` without the caching of the big subobject of the main `case class`?

```
case class ObjectToBeCached() {
   lazy val someAttribute:Option[BigObject] = retrieveBigObjectFromDatabase()
}
```

Thanks for any hint!

**Update**

As it is sometimes, I did not use the correct terminology when originally posting this question. For thus stumbling over this one and have a similar challenge to face.

I was looking for a way to avoid the serialization of a lazy val of the class `ObjectToBeCached` because the lazy val would consume too much cache memory.

Thus, the title should have been **How to avoid the serialization of lazy val?**

Comment: Isn't caching the advantage of `lazy val`?

Comment: What I read from your question: You want the advantage of the caching without caching the object.

Comment: Kind of conditional caching. So, when the object is serialized, it's lazy val shouldn't be serialized for storing it in memcache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you cannot have your cake and eat it too by not having an object cached, yet not needing to get it from the database.  You are free to create an out-of-memory cache yourself (on disk or something) if you are sure you have the disk space and that this is a lot faster than database retrieval.  (But databases are built to be pretty good at this kind of thing.)

If the object is temporary, then try to put it into a computation:

```
lazy val keepThisForever = {
  val cacheThisForRightNow = readFromDB()
  f(cacheThisForRightNow)
  ...
  answer
}
```

or if that is not possible, assign it to a var and manually clear it when you can.

Alternatively, if you want the cached item but only if you have adequate memory to store it, you can use a *soft reference*, which can be encapsulated like so:

```
// Use this to cache expensive computations that are cleared when
// memory gets especially tight (via SoftReference); not thread-safe
class Soft[T,U](t: T)(gen: T => U) {
  private[this] var cache = new java.lang.ref.SoftReference(gen(t))
  def apply(): U = {
    var u = cache.get()
    if (u==null) {
      u = gen(t)
      cache = new java.lang.ref.SoftReference(u)
    }
    u
  }
}
object Soft {
  def apply[T,U](t: T)(gen: T => U) = new Soft(t)(gen)
}
```

Now you can

```
val queryResult = Soft(queryString)(readFromDB)
```

and access this with

```
queryResult()
```

and you'll read from your database whenever you need it.

(If you need thread safety, you have to at least synchronize the call to `apply`, and more if you might try to have multiple threads use the object immediately after it's created.)

If you just mean that you don't want the lazy val serialized (you didn't ask for that in your question originally!), this is what the `@transient` annotation is for.

Comment: Rex, I am sorry not to have asked with the correct terminology. You are right, `@transient lazy val` is exactly what I meant. Thx for the hint.

I write an update to my question so that in future, others with a similar issue get the answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

If what you need long-term from the query is substantially smaller in-memory than the result set itself, you can use this sort of pattern:

```
lazy val queryResult = {
  val resultSet = doTheQuery(...)
  extractQueryInfo(resultSet)
}
```

Now the query will be executed on-demand, the raw query results will be garbage collected and only the derived information will be retained.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that you are interested in creating the value on demand, but not keeping it around forever.  In that case, change `lazy val` to `def`.

Comment: yes, that is of course an option. But in this case, I then have to retrieve the big object several time from the DB.